# How to create an object using matching each element from array?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I would do build this object structure:

```
{ product:'example1', description: 'description1', price: 123 }
```

and more array has, it increments.

```
[
  { product:'example1', description: 'description1', price: 123 },
  { product:'example2', description: 'description2', price: 123 },
  { product:'example3', description: 'description3', price: 123 },
]
```

I have three array for iterate and need to match your indexes, like

```
{"products":elem[0], "description": description[0], "price": price[0]}
```

I tried this:

```
let products = ['Master','Luxe','Simple'];
let ob = []
products.forEach((elem) => {

let price = ['200','340','203'];
let description = ['bla2','bla3','bla4'];

  ob.push({"products":elem, "description": description, "price": price});
```

but it create an array in `description` and `price`, and I would like associate each element index,

but Im stuck. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should move the `price` and `description` arrays outside the scope of the `Array.forEach()`. It doesn't make a difference in this example but good programming sense tells you that these lists would be coming in from some external source and hence should remain in the same scope as the `products` array.

Secondly, in the callback supplied to your `forEach`, you can accept a [second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which is the `index` of the element currently being processed by the `forEach`.

Finally, when pushing objects into the new array, access the index of the corresponding lists, i.e., `description[index]` and `price[index]`. Otherwise the program has no way to know what index you want to access from the list. Instead you had instructed the program to push the array each time.

I've provided a working snippet of the code below.

```js
let products = ['Master', 'Luxe', 'Simple'];
let price = ['200', '340', '203'];
let description = ['bla2', 'bla3', 'bla4'];

let ob = []
products.forEach((elem, index) => {
    ob.push({ 
        "products": products[index], 
        "description": description[index], 
        "price": price[index]
    });
});
console.log(ob);
```

Answer (score 1):

the second parameter of forEach is the current index.  You just need to pass that in to select the other array elements by index.  Eg:

```
let price = ['200','340','203'];
let description = ['bla2','bla3','bla4'];

products.forEach((elem, index) => {
   ob.push({"products":elem, "description": description[index], "price": price[index]});
})
```

Note that this will break if the price or description arrays have less elements, so it might be wise to include a check to make sure the array.length is large enough.